# What to eat: the hen or the egg? Or: repeated link-only answers to link-requesting questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, link-only-answers

The context:

- a couple of days ago I flagged a user for spreading answers without much more than a link to a blog across the site, those answers where deleted
- a couple of minutes ago I have seen the link to the blog again (actually twice)
- [the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16932897/203657) is explicitly asking for links (and has another answer providing one)

What to do? Options:

- could flag the user again: feels slightly off, without knowing his/her history it's just a link-only answer which may or may not be helpful
- could vote to close the question as it basically is a Iam-new-need-help type: feels better, but seeing the close reasons, none seems to apply. It's only flaw seems to be that it attracts link-only answers, which are not welcome.
- ??

Comment: egg is veg or non veg? pls provide me a good link for my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> could vote to close the question

Yes, this is what you should do. There is no reason to raise a moderator flag for things that you can handle yourself.

> none seems to apply

**What?!** How about this one:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

It seems like it fits perfectly to me.

But that only handles the question. For users who chronically post link-only answers, you need to take other steps. A good start would be to leave a comment on one of their answers that explains to them [our policy against this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: missed the off-site resource ;-) Yeah, that's it. As to explaining: already left a comment on one of the answers that got deleted - obviously without much long-term effect ...

Answer (score 4):

Most definitely, the question needs to be closed as:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

I've voted to close it, as have <del>2 others, so far</del> 4 others, so it's now closed.

Don't worry that link-only answers might be slipping through in the meantime. Once it's closed, that's it... no more answers will be accepted!

You can flag any link-only answers for deletion, also.

Comment: seen the close votes - it's deadly to a question being linked on meta ;-) As to the link-only answers: personally, I'm reluctant to do much more than recommending not doing it - as long as it's not serial link-only to one specific resource that smells like (self- ot other) promotion.

Answer (score 4):

With regard to questions specifically asking for links and resources, there actually is an "off-topic" close reason specifically geared to this situation:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam...

With regard to the answers giving nothing but a link you could comment and refer them to the relevant meta discussions:

- [Are link-only answers poor practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice)
- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)
- [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers)

Comment: thanks, overlooked that close reason (too hot here in Berlin ;-) BTW, [my current favourite thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183603/159794) about link-only answers

Comment: @kle - oh, that's a good one too!

Comment: Hot in Berlin? You must be joking. It's been over 100°F (38°C) here in Texas for *weeks*. @kleopatra

Comment: Nevermind the temperature; @cod how on earth do you manage with the humidity there?!?! Do you swim to work???

Comment: @CodyGray here's around the middle to upper thirties since a couple of weeks - and we are not as accustomed to it as you hard-boiled Texans :-)

Comment: Mostly by not working outside. But still, it's horrible. I'm stuck here at least until I finish university. (Personally, I think the heat is worse than the humidity.)

Comment: @CodyGray Hop over to Phoenix and we can chat about the heat in Texas and Arizona.