# What to do with an old "recommend some software" question with several link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, flags

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192082/what-to-eat-the-hen-or-the-egg-or-repeated-link-only-answers-to-link-requesti) is similar, but my question here concerns handling old questions.

A new link-only answer has been posted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201812/any-testing-tool-for-web-gui-load-testing) asked in June 2012. At the time of posting this question there are 934 views and five answers that are links and little explanation. There is one comment, and it also just provides a link to software.

The question appear to be off-topic as it asks for recommendation on software. The answers appear to be wrong because they are just links.

As this question is nearly two years old, it may have been flagged already and been deliberately left as useful. How can learn the history of this question and hence whether I should flag it? Or should I just flag the question ignoring its history?

Comment: If it's off topic, just vote/flag to close. Questions that are off topic and deliberately left are usually locked with the historical lock.

Comment: @3ventic'sShadow - so I should look for a lock or a historical lock. Thanks. I see others have already put the question on hold.

Answer (score 1):

You should flag it. Flagging and closing question is not the same. If you have read the previleges, you'll see that at 3000 reputation points you can cast open-close votes. If the votes are more than 4 or 5, that question will be put on-hold or close. So flagging is just to make it outstanding that it may be need to be closed, but real closing depends on a moderator or a more-than-3000-reputation-points user. However, flagging are useful for them to easily detect which question might nedd to be closed.

I hope you understand.